# White thing that is stuck on the LCD screen cause a weird dot. Any ways to remove it?

Tags: lcd

I have just got that White dirt that cause a weird dot which is probably very rare to get on an LCD screen. As you can see that it it seems to be a stuck or dead pixel. But is not. It has been cause by the white thing that I don't know what cause it. Yes, I touch it with my finger, and other pointy stuff, and it feels like it's either seems removable but it isn't or it's a scratch (But it's probably feels different than a normal and deep scratch).

I use my  I tried using an Eraser, But it doesn't work probably at all. And I have also use the cube tip Vaseline doesn't seem to work but I not completely sure through I tried to follow the steps. I also tried to pulling it with my nail and pen and unfortunately I could not get it off with those.

[image]

[image]

The red marks is where the deep scratch/dirt/White thing is. Probably seems that the glass has broke, it has a hole or a point within the glass or anything else that haves to do with it. The pictures is not clear because either I'm not good taking pictures of that kind or it's the only picture quality and closeness I get.

Any way to get this white thing off that causes a weird dot?

Comment: I have something similar on my monitor that matches your description, and I'm pretty sure that it's a tiny gouge in the screen. Luckily for me, the mark is in an inconspicuous location, and I hardly ever notice it. Unfortunately, I don't have any tips for improving the appearance of the imperfection, but I hope that knowing what it is with a little more certainty may set you on the path toward a solution.

Comment: ugh ugh ugh. Do not use anything other than a soft, lint free cloth + monitor cleaning solution or monitor wipes on a monitor

Comment: I don't know if this is going to help but you can try cleaning it with IPA(isopropyl alcohol).

Comment: In the 1st image, the circled spot is displaying normally.  In the 2nd, it looks like a white spot where it should be fairly dark.  Are you sure the 1st image is pointing to the same spot?

Comment: Yeah it's seem like a gouge. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your pictures are a bit hard to tell, but it sounds like you are describing a scratch on the polarizing layer of your screen (there is a plastic layer on the surface of your screen that manipulated the light, not important here), it can help protect the individual LED pixels, and a scratch or scruff can cause weird colors, or just a white spot. The plastic layer is sort of like a tint/darkening layer. There is no way to fix or repair it, and scrubbing, picking, or poking it will only make things worse, either expanding the spot or damaging the LED itself. Just leave it alone. The only fix is replacing the LED panel itself. (Fairly technical, shouldn't be done unless you know what you're doing)

If it is more of a bright/stuck pixel, you might not have much luck either. There are programs and videos out there that can help unstick them. Give this a try: http://www.jscreenfix.com/ again, if that doesn't work, the only real solution is replacing the panel, and even then it would be one of the control boards causing issues.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are talking about a line/trail of **physical** white dots, which you can scratch off off your screen then maybe its some sort of animal poo or something like a lizard or some insect walked across your screen laying those eggs/poo.

Most notably, these trail of dots seem to be appearing on the backside of the monitor too and am pretty sure its **not** a display issue we are discussing here. These things we can touch, scratch and it comes off pretty easily. Have seen these on other electronics too like on top of my desktop CPU case.

I don't know how to describe it, digging more into this sh*t (*maybe literally* :P ).